# Report returns no data while matching SOQL query does

Tags: reporting, joined-reports

I have a user who made a joint report with 4 blocks, all of them on the same report type.

- The report type gives access to Opportunities, inner join a 1st custom object (let's call it Custom1), inner join a 2nd custom object (let's call it Custom2).
- Each block displays a Sum of a currency opportunity custom field and the name of the Custom2.
- The filters are : `All opportunities (org scope), Opportunity.CloseDate = current year, Custom2.Name contains [a country name, different in each block], Custom2.CancelReason__c in (value1, value2...)`

Run as admin the report returns the expected records, but run with the user it returns no data at all. Yet I can see relevant sample data in edit mode.

After I checked security on every field and object and share settings I made a SOQL query matching the report fields and conditions. **Run with the same user, the query does return** the expected results for each block, while **the report doesn't**.

Also, if I create a report with the same conditions as the ones in a block but not joined, it works. As soon as I define report as *joined*, even not adding any block, I have no record anymore.

Anyone has an idea what could go wrong ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally asked Salesforce support, thanks to them they've been very good on this case.

Here is the answer :

> There are two different causes for this:
>
> 1. Custom report types behave differently from our standard report types when it comes to how roles of users are handled and what
>    Opportunities are visible to certain users. Please have a look at this
>    article for more information:
>    https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326137&type=1&mode=1
> 2. You can not change the role hierarchy for joined reports at the moment. That's why a normal report works but a joined report shows no
>    results, because the settings are not correct. But unfortunately, this
>    can not be changed at the moment. I found this Idea in our Idea
>    Exchange:
>    https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kwOsAAI  If
>    you upvote it and it gets enough upvotes this feature might be
>    implemented in a future release.  I also found this Idea regarding the
>    ability to remove role hierarchy dependency for custom report types:
>    https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzURAAY
>
> This would explain why both users in the same role can not see any
> results in the actual report.  To test this you could temporarily put
> one of the affected users on top of the role hierarchy and run the
> report.
>
> The reason why the report shows some records in the preview mode, is
> that this is only supposed to show the structure of the report, and it
> seems that those role hierarchy filters only get applied properly,
> when the report is run.

None of our opportunities have a Territory set so the user could not see anything in *joined mode*. But in *flat* mode a different rule applies. Weird behaviour on Salesforce's side...

---

In addition they gave me a workaround :

- Create one report per block
- Arrange them in a dashboard

This way the user has a global view of what he needed and ability to display each report for records details.